# Can DirectorySearcher skip the first n1 entries and return the next n2 entries?

Tags: c#, directorysearcher

Is there a way to have DirectorySearcher perform a search that skips over the first, for example, 100 entries and return the first 7 after that?

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't do that in a simple for loop ?

Comment: Could you post the code that is retrieving the list? If you have an IEnumerable, this is possible with Linq

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `searcher` is of type `DirectorySearcher`:

```
searcher.FindAll().OfType<System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult>().Skip(100).Take(7);
```

Cheers

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't stop `DirectorySearcher` from sending back the first 100 entries in the first place (this simply ignores them). Probably the best you can achieve without a different API though...

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is set the `PageSize` property, so that behind the scenes paging is occurring, and then do paging manually as per comments above.

If you need to be able to come back later and restart from a previous position without bringing back all the initial data again, then I think you are out of luck with `DirectorySearcher`